# Firebase reCAPTCHA verifier not working on cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I'm having problem with cordova iOS app and Firebase reCAPTCHA verification.

I'm trying to implement phone number sign-in to my cordova app using method Firebase roughly like this:

```
// DOM:
<div id="recaptcha-verifier-container" />

// Render recaptcha widget
const recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
  'recaptcha-verifier-container',
  { 'size': 'normal' })
recaptchaVerifier.render()

// Sign in after user has completed captcha verification and entered phone number
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, recaptchaVerifier)
```

On cordova android app and plain web app this generates a captcha checkbox widget in iframe (see DOM screenshot) and login works as expected. In iOS app though the captcha widget is not rendered (see DOM screenshot) so user cannot complete it and log in.

Console doesn't provide any helpful messages, but if I open the iOS reCAPTCHA iframe url, I see a widget saying *Could not connect to reCAPTCHA server. Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge* (see screenshot).

I'm using `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` in my project, which makes the whole application to be served through an internal web server on `http://localhost:8080`. I've whitelisted localhost domain from Firebase project settings. This should fix the usual cordova problem, where captcha is not working due to `file:///` protocol.

Do you have any ideas how to fix iOS behavior, or how to debug this issue further?

**Android recaptcha widget DOM (ok)**
[image: Android recaptcha widget - rendered]

**iOS recaptcha widget DOM (not rendered)**
[image: iOS recaptcha widget - not rendered]

**Opening the iOS widget iframe url**
[image]

Comment: Check out this post to make [Firebase Phone Auth in iOS ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190127/10422799)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like working solution 