# ionic firebase phoneAuth without recaptcha on ios

Tags: firebase, ionic4, recaptcha

I have an ionic app where i use firebase phone authentication which uses recaptcha. It works fine on android but throws error on ios saying recaptcha can only be run in an http environment. I would like to know if there's a way to perform firebase phone auth without using recaptcha.

```
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container',{
      'size': 'invisible'
    });


              let appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
              this.appService.sendPhoneVerification(phoneNumber,appVerifier) 
              .then(confirmationResult => {
                   //do something
                })
```

Ios throws error 'RECAPTCHA can only be run in HTTP/HTTPS environment'

Answer (score 2):

Well this is how I solved my issue "'RECAPTCHA can only be run in HTTP/HTTPS environment'".

1. Install the Firebase Plugin :[plugin link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase)
2. Add the it to your app.module.ts.
3. Make a platform check: to check if its iOS.

   `if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
     //ios code here
    } else {
     //android here
    }`
4. Now add the following code (iOS platform) to send a verification code sms to the user to verify the phone number. Inject the plugin into the constructor. Create a variable to assign the data from the promise. Phone number should be country code + number. example '+19999999999'

   `public signInUser(phoneNum) {
     this.firebase.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNum).then((vdata) => {
     this.refConfirm = vdata;
      //you can redirect the person to a verification page or show an alert to 
       input verification code.
    });
   }`
5. Now create a token to verify and sign in user with credentials using firebase.

   `public verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
     let tokenPhone = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(this.refConfirm, 
      phoneNumber);
     firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(tokenPhone).then((verifiedData) => {
       //whatever you want to do here or redirect the user to home page.
     });
   }`
6. Generate your GoogleService.plist on Firebase & add to your project root directory[image]
7. You have to add reversed client id instead of normal one.

   [image]
8. This is how I solved it.

Comment: what about https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-firebase-auth ?